# How to plot histogram/ frequency-count of a vector with ggplot?

Tags: r, vector, ggplot2, histogram

I want to plot with **ggplot** the frequency of values from a numeric vector. With `plot()` is quite straight forward but I can't get the same result with **ggplot**.

```
library(ggplot2)    
dice_results <- c(1,3,2,4,5,6,5,3,2,1,6,2,6,5,6,4)    
hist(dice_results)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dice_results) + geom_bar()
# Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

Should I create a dataframe for `ggplot()` to plot my vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please look at the help page `?geom_histogram`. From the first example you may find that this works.

```
qplot(as.factor(dice_results), geom="histogram")
```

Also look at `?ggplot`. You will find that the data has to be a `data.frame`

Answer (score 31):

Try the code below

```
library(ggplot2)    
dice_results <- c(1,3,2,4,5,6,5,3,2,1,6,2,6,5,6,4,1,3,2,4,6,4,1,6,3,2,4,3,4,5,6,7,1)
ggplot() + aes(dice_results)+ geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white")
```

Comment: The answer doesn't actually explain why it works. Could this be added, since it is the highest voted?

Answer (score 7):

The reason you got an error - is the wrong argument name. If you don't provide argument name explicitly, sequential rule is used - `data` arg is used for input vector.

To correct it - use arg name explicitly:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(dice_results)) + geom_bar()
```

You may use it inside `geom_` functions familiy without explicit naming `mapping` argument since `mapping` is the first argument unlike in `ggplot` function case where `data` is the first function argument.

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(dice_results))
```

**Use `geom_histogram` instead of `geom_bar` for Histogram plots:**

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(dice_results))
```

Don't forget to use bins = 5 to override default 30 which is not suitable for current case:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(dice_results), bins = 5)

qplot(dice_results, bins = 5) # `qplot` analog for short
```

To  reproduce base `hist` plotting logic use breaks args instead to force integer (natural) numbers usage for breaks values:

```
qplot(dice_results, breaks = 1:6)
```