# plot histogram from a vector by ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

i want to plot a histogram by ggplot 2 from a vector. 
the dataset is rivers from datasets packages

```
rivers
  [1]  735  320  325  392  524  450 1459  135  465  600  330  336  280  315  870  906  202  329
 [19]  290 1000  600  505 1450  840 1243  890  350  407  286  280  525  720  390  250  327  230
 [37]  265  850  210  630  260  230  360  730  600  306  390  420  291  710  340  217  281  352
 [55]  259  250  470  680  570  350  300  560  900  625  332 2348 1171 3710 2315 2533  780  280
 [73]  410  460  260  255  431  350  760  618  338  981 1306  500  696  605  250  411 1054  735
 [91]  233  435  490  310  460  383  375 1270  545  445 1885  380  300  380  377  425  276  210
[109]  800  420  350  360  538 1100 1205  314  237  610  360  540 1038  424  310  300  444  301
[127]  268  620  215  652  900  525  246  360  529  500  720  270  430  671 1770
```

at first I tried these but didn't work:

```
> ggplot(rivers,aes(rivers))+geom_histogram()
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
> ggplot(rivers)+geom_histogram(aes(rivers))
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

then i found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025717/how-to-plot-histogram-frequency-count-of-a-vector-with-ggplot) and figured out that i can achieve my goal by:

```
ggplot()+aes(rivers)+geom_histogram()
or
ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(rivers))
```

i read through ggplot help documentation and have following questions:

- why i got error when i claim dataset in either ggplot() or geom_histogram(),like ggplot(data=rivers)? Help docs indicates a vector will be coerced to a data frame by default and a dataset must be specified. My assumption is that when a dataset is not specified, the function will search for global environment?
- why it works when i call aes(rivers) independently or in geom_histogram() but i got error when i put it in gglot(). why the location of aes(rivers) matters in this case?

  > ```
  > ggplot(aes(rivers))+geom_histogram()
  > Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
  > ```

Comment: Looks like you have a `vector`.  Convert it to `data.frame` and then use `ggplot`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't provide argument name to `ggplot` explicitly, then value is assigned to the wrong `ggplot` argument (first in sequential order is `data` arg). Arguments order can be seen on the relevant function help page:

```
?ggplot
```

`ggplot(data = NULL, mapping = aes(), ..., environment = parent.frame())`

Therefore when you provide `aes()` to ggplot without specifying argument name, it's like if you do the following:

```
ggplot(data = aes(rivers)) + geom_histogram()
```

since `data` argument don't allow this data type - you get an error.
providing correct argument name solves the problem:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(rivers)) + geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the error is `rivers` is a `vector`.

```
ggplot(aes(rivers))+
               geom_histogram()
```

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval. Did
>   you accidentally provide the results of `aes()` to the `data`
>   argument?

Convert it to `data.frame` and then it would work

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data_frame(val = rivers) %>%
          ggplot(., aes(val)) + 
                geom_histogram()
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
rivers <- sample(700:1700, 150)
```

Comment: Thanks~ but why it works by ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(rivers)) even without converting the vector to a data frame?

Comment: @Yin  In this method, you are initializing a skeleton ggplot object and the `rivers` is used within the `aes` as a vector.  But, in the other case, if you call `ggplot(rivers) +`, it is not converting to `data.frame` though it says that `data - Default dataset to use for plot. If not already a data.frame, will be converted to one by fortify()`  I am not sure if it is a bug or not

Comment: just one more question~in this case, why the aesthetic mappings cannot be called in ggplot()? But can be called independently or in geom_histogram()?     ^ ^

Comment: @Yin If you look at `?ggplot`, there are multiply ways to call.  the `ggplot()` option is creating a skeleton and the argument inside should be `data`, then `aes`.  Here, the `data` is a `vector` and for some reason it is not `fortified` to `data.frame` though the documentation claims differently

Comment: @Yin, you are relying too much on an argument order you don't actually know. Read what order is expected (which is not the same for `ggplot` and `geom_*`), or use named arguments. There's a ton of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use qplot() which is a shortcut for producing plots quickly. It is a function of ggplot2. The following code will solve your problem:

```
qplot(rivers, geom="histogram")
```